# Culture-independent format for date

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm calling Oracle procedures that have argument date. How can I specify the format of the date so it is recognized by oracle no matter what kind of globalization it uses ?

E.g.

```
create or replace procedure MyProc(p_valid_date in date) ...
```

The client calls the proc, how should I specify p_valid_date as a string ... ?
If I use, e.g., '01212014', i.e. DDMMYYYY then it won't work with US settings. If I use US settings, it won't work in UK. Etc.

In SQL Server, I'd use YYYYMMDD format which is culture invariant but I can't find anything about culture invariant format in Oracle documentation and all kind of formats that I have tried seem to be always bound to the culture.

**UPDATE**
I don't want to use functions because my client does pure procedure call. That's a limitation of my client. I know that I could change the argument into string and then convert the string using to_date inside the procedure but that seems like a pretty poor design.

Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as a date "format", a date is a date, which means that if it's passed as a date rather than a string it will always be a date.

Comment: @Ben - how would you explain Toad call begin MyProc(p_valid_date => '2014-10-20'); end - to me it seems like a string - how would I specify date ?

Comment: That is a string :-). You either pass in a date from your calling code, use a date literal `date 2014-10-20` or convert a string to a date `to_date('2014-10-20'. 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: @Ben :-). Unfortunately, my client is MS SSRS. When a procedure is called you pass *only* arguments. You *can't* pass result of function. I can't make it more clear. Sorry

Answer (score 5):

ISO date format is "invariant" you are looking for:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd/mon.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-----------
07/nov.2014

SQL> select to_char(DATE '2014-12-31') from dual;

TO_CHAR(DAT
-----------
31/dec.2014
```

You can use this notation: `DATE '2014-12-31'`

Comment: Thank you. However, I'd like to do a pure procedure call so I can't use function to_char when passing the argument. I'll clarify the question

Comment: I used `to_char` only to demonstrate that it receives correct date. In your procedure call you can write `MyProc(DATE '2014-12-31')`.